# Eclipse - Cannot find active project

Tags: java, eclipse

I checked out an existing java project, and when I want to build a war file, I'm getting this error:

[image]

Any suggestion? I don't find information about the "Echo application"

Comment: Maybe project metadata are not correct, is not difficult ifyou have a different setup from the original project (different eclipse version, different plugin setup , ecc...).

Comment: How do you triggered the WAR build/export? Via menu, right-click menu, _Quick Access_, ...? If you run the command via _Quick Access_, make sure the project is selected in the _Project Explorer_.

Comment: I was in the package explorer, shame on me